# Android WIFI Status On Powerup After BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, wifi

My device does a Powerup and starts an Application on BOOT_COMPLETED by registering a broadcast receiver.  What attempts will android make to connect to wifi before BOOT_COMPLETED is issued?

To be clear will Android attempt to connect to WIFI before issuing BOOT_COMPLETED?  YES, NO

If YES then

How long, or many times will it attempt this before issuing BOOT_COMPLETED?

Are there any settings that can effect how many times or for how long android will attempt to connect to WIFI during POWERUP before issuing the BOOT_COMPLETED intent?  Can this be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To be clear will Android attempt to connect to WIFI before issuing BOOT_COMPLETED? YES, NO

Maybe. It will depend on device and Android version. Applications should not be relying upon any specific behavior here.

> How long, or many times will it attempt this before issuing BOOT_COMPLETED?

It will depend on device and Android version. Applications should not be relying upon any specific behavior here.

> Are there any settings that can effect how many times or for how long android will attempt to connect to WIFI during POWERUP before issuing the BOOT_COMPLETED intent?

No.

> Can this be changed?

With respect to an SDK application, no.

As a user, you can write your own firmware, or find some existing firmware that allows you to control this behavior. Or, you can use a device that does not have WiFi. Or, you can manually disable WiFi.